# How to pass the function output to another function in powershell?

Tags: powershell

First time to use the PowerShell.

I try to find a way to use the function output as the input of another function.

For an example,

```psh
Function TK
{
    param ([int]$OTK)

    $TK = $OTK * 2

    write-host "TK $TK"
}

Function MAT
{
    param ([int]$OMAT)

    $MAT = $OMAT * $TK /5

    write-host "MAT $MAT"
}
```

The idea is to create a script or a module to call different functions independently. It starts with the first function and pass the ouput to another function as the input. 
The functions can either run independently or run sequentially.

Any Example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All output from functions is passed down the pipe. That is all *output*. You are using `write-host` which is just for displaying on the console itself. Use `Write-Output` or just write the command out with out it. I also suggest you have a look at [about_functions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847829.aspx).

Not exactly sure what the question is but the title as asked I would do something like this.

```psh
Function TK
{
    param ([int]$OTK)
    $OTK * 2
}

Function MAT
{
    param ([int]$OMAT, $TK)
    $OMAT * $TK /5
}
```

The line `$OMAT * $TK /5` could also be read as `Write-Output $OMAT * $TK /5`. They are functionally the same.

I added another parameter for the `MAT` function for the second value `$TK`. You can declare variables using the `global` keyword but this is clear on concise. This would be a sample function call which outputs the result `10`

```
MAT 5 (TK 5)
```

The expression `(TK 5)` is evaluated then sent as the second value for the function `MAT`. You can also use a variable as a middle man but unless you need to use the function calls output more than once this would be redundant.

```
$result = TK 5
MAT 5 $result
```

You can also call functions inside one another just like any cmdlet. It is important though to declare the function before you call it.

```
Function MAT
{
    param ([int]$OMAT)
    $OMAT * TK /5
}
```

Note the "TK" above code will call the function `TK`.

Comment: Thanks Matt.        Still need to ask you something. If there is one more function, the script should be format like: param ([int]$OMAT, $TK,$XX) and call MAT 5 (TK 5 XX 5) ? Or different format ?

Comment: Each separate parameter has to be at least separated by a space. If you need an expression you can enclose the expression in brackets. Based on your comment your call would be `MAT 5 (TK 5) (XX 5)` If you have a _separate_ functions called `TK` and `XX`